# Passing a 2D array into a function

Tags: c, function, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am a newbie and I am doing functions practice. After executing following code, I get the output with a bunch of garbage values. 
What could be the mistake?
Am I passing the 2d arrays into the functions properly?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void populArray (int array[][6], int rows);
void computtotal (int array[][6], int rows);
int main()
{
    int arr[10][6],ave,max;
    populArray( arr, 10);
    computtotal( arr, 10);

    return 0;
}
void populArray (int array[][6],int rows)
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i++;i<rows)
    {
        for (j=0;j++;j<6)
        {
            printf("enter %d and %d th elemnt",i,j);
            scanf("%d",&array[i][j]);
        }
    }
 } 
 void computtotal (int array[][6], int rows)
 {
    int i,j,sum=0;
    for (i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<6;j++)
        {
            sum=sum+array[i][j];
            array[i][5]=sum;
            sum=0;
         }
     }
     for (i=0;i<rows;i++)
     {
        for (j=0;j<6;j++)
        {
            printf("%d",array[i][j]);
         }
         printf("\n");
     }

 }
```

Comment: Your `comuttotal` function seems weird. I don't think it does what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

In `populArray()`

```
for (i=0;i++;i<rows)
{
    for (j=0;j++;j<6)
```

You have swapped the condition check. It should be

```
for (i=0;i<rows;i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<6;j++)
```

---

**NOTE:** 
Use the standard definition of `main()`

```
int main(void) //if no command line arguments.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i=0;i++;i<rows)
```

Is never executed because the condition `i++` returns false.

Should be

```
for (i=0;i<rows;i++)
```

same for

```
for (j=0;j++;j<6)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all variables `ave` and `max` are declared but not used.

```
int arr[10][6],ave,max;
```

Remove them.

Instead of the magic numbers `10` and `6` it is better to use named constants. You could use a variable length array if the compiler supports them or define the constants using the #define directice. For example

```
#define ROWS 10
#define COLS 6

int main( void )
{
    int arr[ROWS][COLS];
    //...
```

Function `populArray` contains invalid records of loops

```
void populArray (int array[][6],int rows)
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i++;i<rows)
             ^^^^^^^^^^
    {
        for (j=0;j++;j<6)
                 ^^^^^^^^
        //...
```

I think you mean the following

```
void populArray( int array[][6], int rows )
{
    int i,j;

    for ( i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < 6; j++ )
        {
            printf( "enter %d and %d th elemnt",i,j );
            scanf( "%d", &array[i][j] );
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that in function `computtotal` you are trying to calculate the sum of all elements in a row and write it in the last element of the row. Otherwise the function does not make a great sense.

If I am right then the function can look like

```
void computtotal( int array[][6], int rows )
{
    int i, j;

    for ( i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
        int sum = 0;

        for ( j = 0; j < 6; j++ )
        {
            sum = sum + array[i][j];
        }

        array[i][5] = sum;
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < 6; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", array[i][j] );
            //      ^^^^^
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}
```

And according to the C Standard function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```